# Microsoft Access crashing with "Invalid Picture" error after trying to "Insert Picture" to image list in design view

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

Basically what the title says. I have an ImageList control in my Access project. When I try to add this certain image, I get an "Invalid Error" popup message and then Access proceeds to crash and I need to restart it. The image is getting added in design time in the ImageListCtrl Properties window.

The image I am trying to upload is a .bmp just like all of the others I have. The only difference with this one is that I had downloaded it as a different file type and used an online converter to make it a .bmp (not sure if that would change anything).

I am using Access 2010.

Comment: Apparently it does. Find another way to get the image to bmp format.

Comment: Yeah, I ended up saving it directly as a bmp and it worked fine. I guess something sketch was going on with that converter.